# How to add loops and compare in stored procedures SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following set of number as a varchar and getting the input as an integer var.

```
@ProductId int
 
DECLARE @AllowedProductIds varchar(max) 
SET @AllowedProductIds ='7002,7058,67,7000,7059,7038'
 
IF (@ProductId = (SELECT CAST(@AllowedProductIds AS INTEGER) 
                  FROM dbo.SplitString(@AllowedProductIds, ','))) 
BEGIN
    SET @boolVariable = 1 
END
```

I want to separate the varchar with a delimiter say in my case (,) and compare each one with the input and return the result from the boolean variable.

This is the following code that I have tried and I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting varchar to int

Can somebody please help me out how to do this?

Comment: which dbms of what version you are using?

Comment: Am using SQL 2016- V 13.0.4

Comment: Any reason you are using a custom `SplitString` function rather than the default `STRING_SPLIT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cast` call is not reading the returned column from the `dbo.SplitString` call, and instead is trying to evaluate the whole input string as an integer, which it is not.

I don't know the schema of the output of your SplitString function, but let's imagine that it returns something like this:

```
Input string: '12345,123,234,345'

Output table:

 SplitStringItem
 12345
 123
 234
 345
```

Then your call should be:

```
if @ProductId IN 
(
    select cast(SplitStringItem AS INTEGER) from dbo.SplitString(@AllowedProductIds, ',')
)
```

Note the change to use the IN operator rather than the = operator, since you're trying to assess whether a single integer value is in a list of possible values.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using SQL Server you can do this

```
declare @AllowedProductIds varchar(max), @ProductId int=67
set @AllowedProductIds ='7002,7058,67,7000,7059,7038'
 
if exists (select * from String_Split(@AllowedProductIds, ',') where Cast(value as int)=@ProductId )
print 'yay'
```

Or alternatively

```
declare @AllowedProductIds varchar(max), @ProductId int=67
set @AllowedProductIds ='7002,7058,67,7000,7059,7038'
 
if exists (select * from String_Split(@AllowedProductIds, ',') where value=Cast(@ProductId as varchar) )
print 'yay'
```

and

```
select @boolVariable=
case when exists (select * from String_Split(@AllowedProductIds, ',') where value=Cast(@ProductId as varchar) )
then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2016 you can use string_split() function to do what you are trying to achieve.

**Query:**

> ```
> DECLARE @ProductId int,@isHavingBoldAccess int
> set @ProductId=7058
>
> DECLARE @AllowedProductIds varchar(max) 
> SET @AllowedProductIds ='7002,7058,67,7000,7059,7038'
>  
> IF @ProductId in
> (
> select * from STRING_SPLIT(@AllowedProductIds, ',')
> )
>
> SET @isHavingBoldAccess = 1 
>
> print @isHavingBoldAccess
> ```

**Output:**

1

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cfdcf090559a271a718940e5fa6456f9)*

Answer (score 0):

You can **Simplify your Code** like  this:

Also the above mentioned Error is resolved here.

If the **@ProductId** matches with the **@AllowedProductIds** String, the we can assign the Value as 1 else it will takes the default value for the variable **@boolVariable**. Here its default value is `NULL`.

```
DECLARE @AllowedProductIds VARCHAR(MAX),
@boolVariable INT,
@ProductId INT=67

SET @AllowedProductIds ='7002,7058,67,7000,7059,7038'

SELECT @boolVariable = 1
FROM String_Split(@AllowedProductIds, ',')
WHERE  CAST(Value AS INTEGER) =@ProductId

SELECT @boolVariable
```